# $Ax = y$, possible to isolate matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the matrix equation of real coefficients

$Ax = y$

where $y$ and $x$ are of different size. Is it possible to do a simple operation which will turn $A$ into a matrix function of both $y$ and $x$? I guess I can multiply on the right side with $x^{\top}$ and divide by the norm to yield the identity-matrix, but is there a smoother way to proceed?

Comment: You are trying to change a linear equation into a nonlinear equation?

Comment: I'm trying to express the matrix A in terms of the vector x.

Comment: You are aware that $A$ is far from being uniquely determined?

Comment: Can it be uniquely determined given that $x \cdot x^{\top}$ yields an invertible matrix? My mathematical background is a little bit rusty here

Comment: Yes.  But, $x x^T$ will yield an invertible matrix if and only if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \neq 0$. In other words, if you are in more than one dimension, it will not work. If $y=Ax$ then we also have $y=(A+B)x$ for any $B$ that satisfies $Bx=0$. The matrix $B$ can be any matrix with rows that are orthogonal to $x$. There are infinitely many such matrices $B$ when $x$ is multi-dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

For an $n\times m$ matrix, the system

$$y=Ax$$

has $nm$ unknowns (the $a_{ij}$) for $n$ equations. This is blatantly insufficient.

---

(By the way, $xx^T$ cannot be invertible as all columns are proportional to each other and the rank is at most $1$.)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't isolate $A$. As a concrete example, take
$$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \quad A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad x = y = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that $y = A_1x$ and $y = A_2x$. So, knowing that $y = A x$ cannot tell you a specific matrix, as it could equally be $A_1$ or $A_2$ (or indeed, any $2 \times 2$ matrix whose first column is $x$).

Multiplying both sides by $x^\top$ will not help, in general. The matrix $xx^\top$ is a $2 \times 2$ rank $1$ matrix (in this case, coincidentally equal to $A_2$). It has no inverse. So, while it's true that $A(xx^\top) = yx^\top$, there is no unique way to solve for $A$, as the example shows.

However, what you *can* do is reconstruct $A$ if you know the value of $Ax$ on a *basis*. So, if you know the value of $A\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $A\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, then you know the whole matrix (indeed, in the case of the standard basis, the former is just the left column of $A$, while the latter is the right column of $A$).

In general, if $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is a basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$ (or $\Bbb{C}^n$, or whatever other field), then the matrix
$$B = \left(\begin{array}{c|c}&&&\\v_1 & v_2 & \dots & v_n \\ &&&\end{array}\right)$$
is an $n \times n$ invertible matrix. Moreover,
$$AB = \left(\begin{array}{c|c}&&&\\Av_1 & Av_2 & \dots & Av_n \\ &&&\end{array}\right),$$
so if you know the value of $Av_i$ for all $i$, then you know the value of $AB$ and the value of the invertible matrix $B$. Compute the inverse of $B$, and you can easily isolate $A$.

Comment: Perhaps “or whatever other field” should say “or any vector space over whatever other field” to prevent misinterpretation.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the solution $A$ will not be unique.  That being said, here's a nice formula for an $A$ that works in terms of $x$ and $y$ using a scaled [Householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).  If $x$ and $y$ are non-zero vectors with $\hat x = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and $\hat y = \frac{y}{\|y\|}$, then we can take
$$
A = \begin{cases} 
\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}(I - 2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}) &\hat x \neq \hat y\\
\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}I & \hat x = \hat y
\end{cases}
$$
where $v = \hat x - \hat y$.

Answer (score 1):

**Does this help?!**

Let $ A\begin{bmatrix} 2  \\ 3  \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ -2 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}$, then we can find $A$ by assuming
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ e & f \end{bmatrix}$$ we get 3 equations
$$2a+3b=10,~ 2c+3d=-2,~ 2e+3f=5$$ as there are 6 unknowns one will get many solutions and hence many matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Plug 
\begin{equation}
x=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

where $1$ is in the $j$-th position, into the equation. Now $y$ gives you the $j$-th column of $A$. You will need to do this for as many times as the columns of $A$, of course.